# Use Django Logic to Add CSS Class based on url with slug

Tags: html, css, django, slug

What I have right now:

A simple personal website with a blog section. When I go to different list items from the navbar, it adds an "activated" class if the li is active. The problem occurs with my blog section.

What I am trying to achieve:

Add the "activated" class when I am in the blog sections and blog posts so the link would be activated. I use slug for my posts urls.

What I have right now and it doesn't work:

**template.html**

```
<li class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == "index" %}activate{% endif %}"><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
<li class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == "blog" %}activate{% endif %}"><a href='/blog/'>Blog</a></li>
<li class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == "photohraphy" %}activate{% endif %}"><a href='/photography/'>Photography</a></li>
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail', args=[self.slug])


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from blog.models import Post
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.list_of_post, name='list_of_post'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post

def list_of_post(request):
    post = Post.objects.all()
    template = 'blog/blog.html'
    context = {'post': post}
    return render(request, template, context)

def post_detail(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    template = 'blog/post.html'
    context = {'post': post}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

I know that I have to add some Jinja logic in the li class but I have no idea how to set it correctly. I guess it has something to do with get_absolute_url. Could someone please suggest a way to do it simply and correctly?

Comment: Please correct the `urls.py` and also add `viewsy.py` if you can :)

Comment: The urls.py seems to work properly. I don't see what I should correct. I've added views.py. Thanks!

Comment: I can see that urls.py are actually models.py - probably you just copied it two times...

Comment: Sorry about that. I've just fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: The solution proposed below - it's a quite good start :) Should be enough for you. The problem with that is that you need always remember on passing the attrrbute to the context (on each view). The other approach can be just generating the menu on the backend side ;) as a tuple - then you probably will have much more control and store all of the metadata in one place - but thinks that currently it is just too complicated.

Comment: I have a slug at the end of the url: eg /blog/this-is-a-post. How to I insert that logic into my hmtl file? Coult you please show me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that all the pages are rendered without ajax calls. In that case, whatever page you are rendering you can simply pass the name of page in context `for eg. return self.render_to_response({'page': 'index'})` if its a rendered at `index` url. Then in template you can use simple if condition and set activated class. For eg.

```html
<li class="{% if page == "index" %}activate{% endif %}"><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
<li class="{% if page == "blog" %}activate{% endif %}"><a href='/blog/'>Blog</a></li>
<li class="{% if page == "photography" %}activate{% endif %}"><a href='/photography/'>Photography</a></li>
```

Comment: Hello Rajesh. Thank you for the solution. Could you please be more precise? I don't quite understand what do I need to change,

Comment: See when you click any of the link in your list, a request is sent back and there is a view that is processed, right. Now from this particular view you can send a variable back to template telling the template which page it is. Further in your template where you have created those `li` based menu you can put in if condition as I have demonstrated to check if the variable equates to the page the link is directing to. If yes add class activated. Thats it. So, in your view that is pointed by `/blog/` in return `self.render_to_response({'page': 'blog'})`

Comment: I've tried your method and it doesn't work. Clearly I'm doing something wrong. Could you please point exactly what do I need to change in my code in order for it to work? Thank you!

Comment: your url points to a view right? so in that view, override your get_context_data() and add a new context like context['link_xxx'] = True. Then in your template, in the anchor tags, add the class is if condition like .. `<a href="{% url 'some_url' %}" class=" {% if link_xxx %} active {% endif %} ">`. PS: its better if you use http referer to determine current link and pass context accordingly